# No login username, password required on new NOOBS install?

Tags: boot, login

Just reloaded NOOBS on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B rev 1.1
os version "9 (stretch)?
no login prompt on boot to CLI
I want it back. How?

Comment: Second pass thru raspi-config and all is well.   Must have exited before without actually selecting.   Thanks... works fine now

Answer (score 2):

You can change the boot options (boot to desktop or CLI and with or without a password) by using raspi-config:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then select:

**3 Boot Options**

then

**B1 Desktop/CLI**

Select your desired boot mode:

**B1 Console         Text console, requiring user to login**

**B2 Console Autologin Text console, automatically logged in as 'pi' user**

**B3 Desktop           Desktop GUI, requiring user to login**

**B4 Desktop Autologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user**

and finally, click:

**OK**

Reboot your Pi to confirm it is working.